# Can I connect to Cloud API using Java code?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, external-calls, java, webservices, api

I have a Java program that connects to a Mathematica Kernel, installed on my computer. I am able to call the APIs and receive the expression results, like to the code below. But is there any cloud services which we can connect like desktop version? Pleas help me. thanks

```
public static KernelLink ml;
        try
    {
        String s = "-linkmode launch -linkname 'E:\\Software\\mathematica\\mathkernel.exe'";
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(s);
        ml.connect();
        ml.discardAnswer();

        String re = ml.evaluateToOutputForm("2 + 3",0); 
        // I want to connect to remote services ,
        // instead of local kernel link
    }
```

Comment: By cloud API do you mean cloudevaluate and similar Cloud* symbols or deployed ApiFunctions?

Comment: I mean, the same thing, instead of having methematica intalled on my computer, I thought there might be a cloud version. instead of giving a local address to connect , a url or something, like remote API. To call evaluateToOutputForm() as a remote function.